# divide RGB-NIR data(.tif) to RGB and NIR data

Tags: image, rgb, tiff, divide

I want to know how to divide RGB-NIR dataset ( .tif file ) to RGB and NIR dataset.

But It's shape is looks like (320,480,3). is it right data shape of RGB-NIR dataset? if it is, I want to know how to divide it into RGB and NIR datasets.

Comment: That doesn't look right, because the 320 and 380 are likely the image width and height, while the 3 is the number of channels and looks to only be sufficient for RGB without the 4th NIR band. However, it is hard to say unless you share the file.

Comment: well, it was the wrong dataset. thankyou !